# About the order Set List

Tags: python-3.x

I have a problem, I want to list the different words in 2 words with set_list. This is my code;

```
def set_word(str1,str2):
    set_list=set()
    for i in str1:
        if i not in str2:
            set_list.add(i)
    for i in str2:
        if i not in str1:
            set_list.add(i)
    return set_list

str1=str(input("word1:"))
str2=str(input("word2:"))
x=set_word(str1,str2)
result=""
for i in x:
    result+=i
print("Different word:",result)
```

Actually, my code works the way I want it. But every time the 'result' sequence is different.

e.g:
first try:

```
      result="abc"
```

e.g:
second try:

```
      result="bca"
```

What is the reason of this?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: `set_word` returns a set, in python `sets` are an unordered collection of objects, when you do `for i in <set>:`, the order in which you iterate over those items is arbitrary, resulting in you getting different words

Answer (score 0):

Python `str` has a per-program-execution hashing seed that perturbs the hash code to protect against denial of service attacks on web APIs. The hash of a `str` is largely responsible for determining which "bucket" in the `set` it ends up in, so by changing the hash on each run, the bucket selected changes each time. Even within the same run of Python, a `set` with identical contents, but constructed in a different way (elements added in different orders, elements being deleted and re-added, etc.) can end up with different ordering due to bucket collisions, but from run to run you're almost guaranteed different ordering.

Comment: I didn't know that, I'm thankful to you!